# Active Directory - Certificate Based Authentication - Multiple certificates for user

Tags: active-directory, ldap, certificate, certificate-authority, ejbca

First, I have very limited knowledge about AD.

Problem:
I authenticating users on AD using user certificates. I want to authenticate user on various devices (including mobile devices). Each will generate its own certificate via a CA. The CA is tied up with AD, so user authenticates on AD via certificates.

On the question is:
**Can a user account on AD hold multiple certificate for a single user. Because in my case the private key will not be share between devices (Devices will connect with CA to retrieve its own identity cert)**

Please help

Comment: Questions asking "Is there a way to do X?" / "Can I do X?" / "Is it possible to do X?" are rarely appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. The answer is usually "yes", but sometimes "no". Either way, the question is usually not very effective. In addition, what is usually meant is "How can I do X?", which will often, but not always, be too broad for Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to clarify what it is you want. Right now, this is a "yes"/"no" question. Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273)